# How to change a file format from rows to columns?

Tags: unix

file format change : top to bottom <> left to right

input file format:

```
100
150
200
300
500
```

output file format should be:

```
100,150,200,300,500
```

I need to apply this in reverse, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace the linefeeds by comma:

```
$ tr '\n' ',' < input.txt > output.txt
```

and reverse

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Yours is much cleaner. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/sh
   i=0
   while read line ; do
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        if [ $i -eq 1 ] ; then
            echo -e "$line\c"
        else
            echo  -e ",$line\c"
        fi
   done  < filename
   echo
```

Use this shell script to convert the \n as , 
The drawback in the tr command is end of the line one comma will be there to overcome
that use this script.